# Dual boot with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: windows, windows-8, system-installation

I have a laptop that had Windows 7 previously installed but now has Windows 8.1. I want to dual boot with Ubuntu 13.10. But I was curious on how to do this properly and in the case that GRUB messes up my computer just delete it and restore it to the original Windows bootloader. Also DON'T recommend EasyBCD. I don't mind using GRUB but I want to be sure I can remove Ubuntu and GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing that one week earlier and that was a total crap (got grub rescue screen)! I finally simply boot on a live cd of Ubuntu 13.10, delete all the partition and reinstall Windows 7 and then alongside Ubuntu 13.10.

Be carefull saving your data before trying that!

Comment: So Ubuntu missed up your Win8.1 installation so you had to delete all the partitions and do a complete re-install of both OSs?

Comment: So basically after installing Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows 8, I needed to do a boot repair in order to fixe a boot problem (my Ubuntu partition wasn't showing up in the boot even if I was going trough the special option of Windows 8 to boot on an other partition). I might have as well made a mistake here configuring repair boot (there is lot of things to configure specialy between UEFI bios and older one). I complete reinstall both OS (except I put windows 7 instead of windows 8 because I totally hate this os).

Answer (score 0):

insert your Ubuntu Live CD and install boot repair and then run it.
for more detailed instructions see the 
[link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

in short add ppa `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`

install bootrepair `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)`

Use recommended settings

Comment: forgot if you wanna remove ubuntu isn the future you can simply format Ubuntu partition and use your windows disk to rewrite mbr and there are many other ways too